# PDF from HTML String with HTML tags in C# ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, itext

I am using ITextSharp to create PDF from HTML String. I have written following code, But If strReplace is a my HTML string with tag, How I generate PDF using itextSharp in C# ?

```
      MemoryStream PDFData = new MemoryStream();
      Document document = new Document(PageSize.LETTER, 50, 50, 80, 50);
      PdfWriter PDFWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, PDFData);
      PDFWriter.ViewerPreferences = PdfWriter.PageModeUseOutlines;


     document.Open();
     AddOutline(PDFWriter, "", document.PageSize.Height);

     document.Add(new Paragraph("\r\n"));

       StringBuilder strReplace = new StringBuilder();
       strReplace.Append(strTemplate);


                        var query = (from c in objAMSContainer.tblincomes
                                     join o in objAMSContainer.tblincomedetails on     c.colId equals o.ColId
                                     where c.colId == 9
                                     && c.colIsDeleted == false
                                     select new { c.colId, o.colQuantity, o.colPrice, o.colAmount }).ToList();

                        for (int j = 0; j < query.Count; j++)
                        {

                            // strReplace.Replace("[ITEM]", Convert.ToString(query[j].colId));
                            strReplace.Replace("${QTY}", Convert.ToString(query[j].colQuantity));
                            strReplace.Replace("${PRICE}", Convert.ToString(query[j].colPrice));
                            strReplace.Replace("${TOTAL}", Convert.ToString(query[j].colAmount));

                        }
```

Comment: strReplace is my Final string with HTML code, What should i write to generate PDF from same.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best way to do it, but you can run it though the HTML to PDF converter iText has.

```
// convert string to stream
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strReplace);
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);


//get the XMLWorkerHelper Instance
XMLWorkerHelper worker = XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance();
//convert to PDF
worker.parseXHtml(PDFWriter , document, stream);

//close the document
   document.close();
   //close the writer
   pdfWriter.close();
```